# How to create a hidden iframe in javascript and put its source code in to and textbox and as variable?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, textbox

This is what i want to do. I want to create a hidden iframe in javascript that points to external website and then use javascript to get the html source code of that hidden iframe into a textbox and as variable(possibly doing some error checking if iframe doesn't load and ask the user to reload...) so far i tried this but how to make it hidden and read source code from it ?Thanks in advance.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://www.somesite.com/");
ifrm.style.width = 640+"px";
ifrm.style.height = 480+"px";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
</script>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I think in most cases this is not possible in just JS.

Comment: You **cannot** access an **external** website. Point. Read about [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: how about if the page is from same domain? how i can read its source code?

Comment: Here you have article how to get content from iFrame https://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/18/get-the-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript-crossbrowser-solution-for-both-ie-and-firefox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with iframe because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), but you can using some server side, using php it will be something like:

```php
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
   $ch = curl_init(); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_GET['url']); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
   echo curl_exec($ch); 
   curl_close($ch);
}
```

and you can call that script with ajax (using jQuery it will be)

```
$.get('script.php', {url: 'http://www.somesite.com/'}, function(page) {
   alert(page);
});
```